# HttpClient Получить дефолтные cookies

Tags: c#, httpclient

Каким образом можно получить сразу же дефолтные куки PHPSESSID, _identity, _csrf
,mg_token. Postman автоматически получает эти куки, а вот на C# не пойму как сделать, Учитывая что куки Mpop должен быть обязательно кастомный т.е он сразу же будет вписан

```
var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
                                {
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("chest_id", "321924534"),
                                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("paid", "0")
                                });



  var userStat1 = await SendRequest2(new Uri("https://wf.mail.ru/minigames/craft/api/open"), content: content); 



private async Task<string> SendRequest2(Uri uri, Uri referrer1 = default, ByteArrayContent content = default)
               {
                string data;
                var cookies = new CookieContainer();
                using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { CookieContainer = cookies })

                using (var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority)) })
                {
                    string uri1 = Convert.ToString(uri);
                    cookies.Add(new Uri(uri1), new Cookie("Mpop", "1510214264:597e5906745e0d7a1905001017031f05001017031f05001017031f051c525a194742:mail12@bk.ru:"));
                    cookies.Add(new Uri(uri1), new Cookie("PHPSESSID", Value));
                    cookies.Add(new Uri(uri1), new Cookie("_identity", Value));
                    cookies.Add(new Uri(uri1), new Cookie("_csrf", Value));
                    cookies.Add(new Uri(uri1), new Cookie("mg_token", Value));
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Referrer = referrer1;
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36");
                    var htmll = await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
                    data = await htmll.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }
                return data;
            }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]